# Creating a void Promise which wraps executable code

Tags: swift, promisekit

I need to wrap some code in a promise using [PromiseKit](http://promisekit.org). I can create a void promise like this:

```
let promise = Promise(value:()) // Void promise.
```

But that's immediately resolved where as I want to return a void promise that wraps some code which is executed as part of the normal promise chain. I can do this:

```
let promise = Promise<Void> {fulfilled, _ in
    // Here is where I do stuff.
    fulfill()
}
```

But this feels kinda clunky.

Is there a more succinct way to generate a void promise that executes code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do the same. I think it's the only existing way. If you don't wan't to create promise object you can do following:

```
self.client.delete(device: device)
    .then { result -> Promise<Void> in
         // do something with result
         return Promise(value: ())
    }
    .catch {
         // handle
}
```